# Not sure which Arduino to pick

Tags: arduino-uno, node.js

Is the Arduino Uno the best one to purchase for a complete beginner?

I eventually want to get into building Nodebots since I already have experience writing Nodejs web-based applications.

Or should I go directly to purchasing an Arduino Starter Kit? SparkFun Inventors Kit? Adafruit ARDX Experimentation Kit for Arduino? Seeed Studio ARDX starter kit? or Freetronics Experimenter’s Kit for Arduino?

I don't know the difference between these and based off what I have shared about my situation so far, which one should I start with to A. Learn the Basics, B. Evolve into developing Nodebots.

Comment: Start simple, buy a cheap arduino uno clone from aliexpress: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-high-quality-UNO-R3-MEGA328P-CH340G-for-Arduino-Compatible-NO-USB-CABLE/32231525607.html Learn how to use the arduino ide with the arduino board, and while you do that, you can investigate where to go next. It can be circuitpython, or esp32 with wifi, or a arduino mkr board or the nodebots. A arduino fan does not have just one arduino board, but a box full of things to tinker with. You need an extra driver for those cheap clones: http://www.wch.cn/downloads/CH341SER_EXE.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeBots does external control of Arduino with Java Script. The controlling computer is a PC or a SOC like Raspberry PI. (Eventually Raspberry can run NodeBots without Arduino.)

For NodeBots, Arduino board runs a firmware called Firmata which executes the commands sent by the Johnny-Five Java Script firmata master library.

I would recommend you to learn C++ and Arduino functions and libraries and code the Arduino directly without Firmata and a controlling computer.